# What is word reversal $w^R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, definition

In the following context, what is the *formal* meaning of "reversal of word $w$"?

> The free monoid on $A$ is the syntactic monoid of the language $\{ ww^R\ |\ w \in A^*\}$, where $w^R$ denotes the reversal of word $w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, elements of $A^*$ are *finite sequences* of $A$, that is, *functions* $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to A$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. Then, if $w=(a_1,\dots,a_{n})$ then we define
$$w^R:= (a_n,\dots,a_1):=i\mapsto a_{n+1-i}$$

Comment: Two more questions: (1) What is the reason behind defining the language $\{ ww^R\ |\ w \in A^*\}$ this way? That is, why "add" reversal of words (tokens, strings, etc.) to the definition of some formal language $L$, as opposed to "just" $Σ^*$? (2) Does $ww^R$ imply $w*w^R$? If so, what is the author indicating by this operation in the set-builder notation?

Comment: A language is a *subset* of $\Sigma^*$, this case we take the set of *palindromes of even length*. For the other question, I'm not entirely sure what $w*w^R$ wants to denote -- my first guess would be indeed the same as $ww^R$.

Comment: Could you show me one element of the image of $\{ww^R\ |\ w \in Σ^*\}$, where $Σ$ is $\{a,b,c,\dots\}$, so that I may understand what is meant by $ww^R$? If I presume composition in $ww^R$ implies $w \cdot w^R$, then would the example be {eviloliveoliveevil} or {(evilolive, oliveevil)}?

Answer (score 2):

If $w=a_1a_2\cdots a_n$, then $w^R=a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_2a_1$